# Interpolation, advantages and disadvantages

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

So during our numerics course we learned a few interpolation methods Aitken/Neville, divided differences,Lagrange and the Vandermonde matrix. How these work is clear to me for the most part, I'm just wondering what are the advantages and disadvantages of the respective methods compared to each other? I know about a few things here and there like some methods being easier to expand when gaining new points but our script seems a bit sparse on that info and I'd like a more holistic picture.